# Web Scraping not working with grid layout

Tags: excel, vba

I want to extract the table which is available from the below website but i am not able to do that with the Get data option from excel.

Is there any other way that I can scrap the live table to my excel ?

https://portal.emsa.europa.eu/web/th...ent-detentions

Comment: Have you looked at any of the web scraping questions on here? many even have code.

Comment: Show your code, error messages, desired results, actual output ...

Comment: Your example url needs a proper login to see the data table.

Comment: @dbmitch I normally don't use any code to do web scrapping.. I usually use Get data option from excel and import it accordingly. But this time it is not working cause the URL which I provided has grid layout not HTML hence it is not working. I just want to know any solutions to get the grid layout table. My URL doesn't required Login credentials. Anyone can access the table.

Comment: @SolarMike yes I have gone thru all the similar post but it is not working either.

Comment: The tag "web scraping" has over 42000 questions, so you checked all?

Comment: @solarmike not all... I checked random posts which relates to my requirement.. however I found some but indeed it doesn't work.

Comment: For me, your url redirects to https://portal.emsa.europa.eu/home - I assume that's because login has been done in the past and cookies are used to save your login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible workaround :

Load directly the .json containing data (limit of 50 results per request) with "Data > Get & Transform > From Web".

Then, with PowerQuery, unnest and select the variables of interest.

Tested with the following .json (inspect the network requests with your browser devtools):

Example :

https://portal.emsa.europa.eu/o/portlet-public/rest/detention/getCurrentDetentions.json?_dc=1653155551216&page=1&start=0&limit=20

Output :

[image: Data_Detention]

EDIT : PowerQuery code :

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://portal.emsa.europa.eu/o/portlet-public/rest/detention/getCurrentDetentions.json?_dc=1653155551216&page=1&start=0&limit=20")),
    results = Source[results],
    #"Converti en table" = Table.FromList(results, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Column1 développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converti en table", "Column1", {"id", "imoNumber", "shipName", "shipType", "detentionDate", "detentionPort", "detentionReportingAuthority", "flag"}, {"Column1.id", "Column1.imoNumber", "Column1.shipName", "Column1.shipType", "Column1.detentionDate", "Column1.detentionPort", "Column1.detentionReportingAuthority", "Column1.flag"}),
    #"Column1.shipType développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Column1 développé", "Column1.shipType", {"description"}, {"Column1.shipType.description"}),
    #"Column1.detentionPort développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Column1.shipType développé", "Column1.detentionPort", {"name", "country"}, {"Column1.detentionPort.name", "Column1.detentionPort.country"}),
    #"Column1.detentionPort.country développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Column1.detentionPort développé", "Column1.detentionPort.country", {"description"}, {"Column1.detentionPort.country.description"}),
    #"Column1.flag développé" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Column1.detentionPort.country développé", "Column1.flag", {"description"}, {"Column1.flag.description"}),
    #"Colonnes permutées" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Column1.flag développé",{"Column1.id", "Column1.imoNumber", "Column1.shipName", "Column1.flag.description", "Column1.shipType.description", "Column1.detentionDate", "Column1.detentionPort.name", "Column1.detentionPort.country.description", "Column1.detentionReportingAuthority"}),
    #"Colonnes supprimées" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Colonnes permutées",{"Column1.id", "Column1.detentionReportingAuthority"})
in
    #"Colonnes supprimées"
```

Comment: this is the output i expected but why it is not working on my report. Can you please show your snapshot of Power query editor.?

Comment: OK. PowerQuery syntax has been added.